# Calculate (or estimate) $S(t)=\sum_{j=0}^k \binom k j |t-j|^{k-1}$.

Tags: inequality

Let $t\in\mathbb R$. Calculate, or estimate from above and below,  the following sum
$$S(t)=\sum_{j=0}^k \binom k j |t-j|^{k-1}.$$
I have not any idea.